# HeaderRight Buttons are not clickable (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, frontend, react-native-navigation

I am experiencing an odd bug with the React Native Navigation v5 headerRight Buttons. I currently have a TouchableOpacity set as a headerRight component in the react native navigation screen; however, the onPress event is not being triggered. There seems to be an invisible object in the middle of the header (title area) that has an absolute position, which prevents the onPress event from being registered. I tried playing around with the zIndex and headerMode values; however, the button is still not pressable. I can only press the button when it is placed on the far right of the screen (i.e. marginRight: 0). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, I am encountering the same issues as the following thread: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7052

Example of my Code

```js
<StackNavigator.Navigator headerMode='screen'>
  <StackNavigator.Screen
    name='Home'
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {}}
        >
          <Text>Button Text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }}
  />
</StackNavigator.Navigator>
```

Comment: This code looks right. Did you confirmed its not calling `onPress`.  Try to some `console.log` in `onPress`.

Comment: Yeap, I have an event that is triggered inside the onPress function. It activates when I press on the far right corner of the button, but when the button is moved towards the center of the header, the button is no longer pressable. There seems to be a view on top of the build in header that blocks the onPress event, but I cannot seem to find a way around this.

Comment: Managed to figure this out. Setting HeaderTitle to an empty view removes the floating view that was blocking the button. Hope this helps someone 

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the following packages seems to have resolved it for me:

```
"@react-navigation/stack": "5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/native": "5.7.4",
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ravi. I have my packages updated to the latest version, but that didn't seem to fix the issue. However, I managed to figure this out. Setting HeaderTitle to an empty view removes the floating view that was blocking the button.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone else, I wrote this piece of code and it the touchable was not clickable but replace <> with <View/*> and it works

```js
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => console.log("clicked")}>
                    <>
                        {showCheckBoxes && <Text style={{color: "white"}}>Cancel</Text>}
                        {!showCheckBoxes && <View style={{padding: 5, marginRight: 15}}>
                            <Ionicons name="md-trash" size={22} color="white"/>
                        </View>}
                    </>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            ),
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to give higher values to zIndex may be 100 or give headerMode: float if that not also not works try updating your packages .